# org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing

Tags: java, hibernate, исключения

Имеется следующая модель:
CarService:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Table
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CarService extends BaseEntity {

  @Column
  private String address;
  @OneToMany
  @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
  @Cascade(CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
  private List<PairSparePartCount> sparePartsCount;
  @OneToMany
  @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
  @Cascade(CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
  private List<Master> masters = new ArrayList<>();
  @OneToMany
  @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
  @Cascade(CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
  private List<Request> requestList;
}
```

PairSparePartCount:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Table
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class PairSparePartCount extends BaseEntity {

  @ManyToOne
  @Cascade(CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
  private SparePart sparePart;
  @Column
  private Integer count;
}
```

SparePart:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Table
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class SparePart extends BaseEntity {

  @Column
  private String name;
  @Column
  private String carBrand;
  @Column
  private String carModel;
  @Column
  private Double price;
}
```

Когда пытаюсь сохранить CarService со списком PairSparePartCount , которых ещё не существует в базе вылетает Exception:

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: by.bsuir.model.PairSparePartCount; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: by.bsuir.model.PairSparePartCount
```

Необходимо чтобы при сохранении CarService , если какой-то PairSparePart нет в списке она создавалась автоматически, насколько я понимаю это Cascade , но почему не работает SAVE_UPDATE ?